# PHP How to prevent mail from leaking script and IP in header

Tags: php, email, header, phpmailer, email-headers

I'm using PHPMailer to send out an email.

In the raw message of the email, the header contains

`X-PHP-Script: /path/to/my/script.php myip6address, myip4address`

I edited into the php.ini these settings

```
[mail function]
mail.add_x_header = 0
add_x_header = 0
```

In my php script, when I use `ini_get("mail.add_x_header")`, it returns `"0"`.

```
// to try and erase the info from the global server var
$_SERVER = Array();

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom("me@mysite.com");
$mail->addAddress("foo@gmail.com");

// to try and override it, instead it just appends and keeps the original header
$mail->addCustomHeader("X-PHP-Script", "No.");
$mail->Subject = "This is a test";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "hello world";

if($mail->send() == false)
{
    var_dump("failed to send mail", $mail->ErrorInfo);
}
```

It still sends my scripts location and my IP address with every email I send.

It also sends it if I use `mail()` instead of PHPMailer, but I assume PHPMailer uses `mail()` under the hood.

How can I disable that header entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why your ini settings are not suppressing that. PHPMailer does indeed use `mail()` by default, but you should try using SMTP to localhost instead as it’s both faster and safer than `mail()`, and will give you control over all the headers. All you have to do is:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

And the default settings should be fine.

Comment: I ended up using `IsSendMail()` to use `sendmail.exe` instead of `mail()`, but it would be nice if there was a solution for `mail()`